# get cell value from a dynamic table in HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I use Javascript to dynamically add new row to a html table, then I used:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
queue.innerHTML +=table.rows[rowCount].cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue + "/" +  table.rows[rowCount].cells[2].firstChild.nodeValue +"\n";
```

But it only returned null, thus I wonder that can we get value from cells form row which was dynamically added and how? 
Thank you.

Comment: 1)Where does queue come from? 2)rowCount is the amount of rows +1, so your logic can't be really right for grabbing something. 3)We need to know your html structure. 4)JavaScript doesn't care if the nodes were dynamically created or not. It just cares that they exist when the code executes. See http://jsfiddle.net/9pL23/

Answer (score 1):

I think the `rows` collection is a zero based array like structure. So try using `rowCount-1`:

```
queue.innerHTML += table.rows[rowCount-1].cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue 
                   + "/" +  
                   table.rows[rowCount-1].cells[2].firstChild.nodeValue +"\n";
```

Furthermore, you can use `innerText`, as in `table.rows[rowCount-1].cells[1].innerText` to get the cell value

[**edit**] skip the rowCount part: you are assigning it before the addition, so `rowCount` should work. You should read [this](http://www.ideyatech.com/2009/07/solution-for-innerhtml-in-table-not-working-in-ie/) though, because `innerHTML` for tables doesn't always give the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think nodeValue is the right thing to use. Per [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue) the nodeValue of an element is always null.

If you are dynamically creating the table rows, wouldn't it make more sense to add it to queue.innerHTML at the same time instead of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it with jQuery, if I understand your question correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $lastRow = $('table tr:last');
  queue.innerHTML += $lastRow.find('td:eq(1)') + '/' + $lastRow.find('td:eq(2)')
</script>
```

Or `:eq(0)` and `:eq(1)` if you want the first and second cell.

Comment: He didn't ask for jQuery. Why does everyone force-feed jQuery these days? You don't need Sizzle to select a DOM element.

Comment: I know. But I thought I'd suggest it, since it's soo much easier for a JS newbie. And everyone else.

Comment: It wasn't really suggesting as it was "here's how you do it". I don't see how it's easier to use jQuery than to use `document.getElementById`; the latter is a gazillion times faster and self-documenting. If you're worried about cross-browser compatibility, I'm pretty sure he doesn't care about Netscape 1.