# HTML table data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I am developing a site in which I am creating a table dynamically using PHP by fetching the data from the form. I need to keep a button for each row in the table so person can click on the button and the popup will appear.. So, my question is, how do we get the data of the dynamically generated table (since one of the columns is the primary key in mysql DB table)?

[get cell value from a dynamic table in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753503/get-cell-value-from-a-dynamic-table-in-html) I went through this but I couldn't find satisfactory answer..

document.getElementById does not help me since there can be thousands of record and I can't name each row and all.. so please... help..

Comment: please try to make your question clearer ! and also include some example or code that you have tried .. so we can help

Comment: Why doesn't `document.getElementById` help you? Since you are generating the table, you can generate the IDs also.

Comment: In order to name the row, use a php while loop when rendering the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table tr').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();
            var camp_id=$(this).find('td').get(0).innerHTML;
            alert(camp_id);               
        });
```

This was the answer ! Finally figured it out !  Thanks everyone anyways ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can name each row. Just give the row the id row_###### or just ###### where that is the primary key identifier for that group of data. Your button will call the javascript myPopup('#######').

Comment: Sorry guys newbie here. Erik can u please elaborate?? and i want to get the data in my <td> tag of clicked <tr> how to get that? naming and accessing it through jquery is quite unclear to me. Can you suggest any links so i can get any tutorial for such things?

Comment: Don't worry about it. We were all newbies at one point. I personally enjoy answering questions like this one.

Comment: can you help me out please?